# Referencing linked server with instance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, linked-server

I have linked two SQL Servers and am trying to insert from one into the other.

The issue is that the server I am inserting into is actually an instance (`COMPANY\INSTANCE`).

When I run my code, how do I reference a table in the linked server? I have tried `Company\instance.dbo.table` but am getting a syntax error because of the backslash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[Company\instance].dbo.table`

Comment: I knew it would be something simple! Thanks